# Filemaker 13 to Firebird SQL connection?

Tags: php, sql, firebird, filemaker

I need to exchange data between Filemaker 13 Pro or Server and Firebird SQL DB.

ODBC is not supported between both only MS SQL, MYSQL and Oracle.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Probably offtopic... try the DBA site.

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com. it's totally database oriented, and will probably be of more use than this site (SE), which is most generalized.

Comment: But ODBC **is** supported by Firebird and there also is ADO/OLE-DB provider

Comment: According to the filemaker documentation, it supports generic ODBC, but for a feature called 'relationship graph' they only support MS SQL, MySQL and Oracle

Comment: I used the Plugin MBS to solve this problem.